# Error on client connections: invalid values of 'columnLabel'

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench, amazon-rds

I am MySQL user with workbench and Amazon RDS

Every time I try to access MySQL client connections I get this error:

[image]

```
Unhandled exception:
DbMySQLQuery.resultFieldStringValueByName():
MySQL_ResultSet::isNull: invalid values of 'columnLabel'

Check the log for more details
```

[image]

The user I am using has all the accesses of an admin/root

This error does not happen to all users, only to some

Am I forgetting to provide some kind of permission?

Answer (score 15):

The proposed solution "[3 Feb 16:10] Adam Latchem" worked for me, in the context of MySQL Workbench connecting to a MariaDB database. The fix (for definiteness) is to edit the file C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Workbench 8.0 CE\modules\wb_admin_connections.py at line 346, to change it from

```
("DB", mforms.StringColumnType, "DB", 100),
```

to

```
("db", mforms.StringColumnType, "DB", 100),
```

(note change of case in first argument).

OS Paths:

Linux (Ubuntu): `/usr/lib/mysql-workbench/modules/wb_admin_connections.py`

MacOS: `/Applications/MySQLWorkbench.app/Contents/Resources/plugins/wb_admin_connections.py` - by @QuickPrototype

Comment: Excellent - this worked perfectly for Mariadb which was failing in client connections previously.  Thank you.

Comment: For those with the apple persuasion: /Applications/MySQLWorkbench.app/Contents/Resources/plugins/wb_admin_connections.py

Comment: This worked for me for connections to Amazon Aurora for MySQL.

Answer (score 1):

There is a solution in this link that worked for me on version 8.0.28:

https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=102465

See entry "[3 Feb 16:10] Adam Latchem"

Comment: it is best to copy paste the entry from external sources.